# Question Templates

Tags: feature-request

I was a little bit more active on DA since a while. And I observed that it seems necessary to flag quite a large percentage of new questions to be closed as "too broad" or "unclear what you're asking". Most of all it's because many new questions are lacking detailed and specific information.

Is it possible to get some minimum question template to encourage askers to provide more profitable questions? To keep moderator's work and time amount to make the questions fit low?

```
<!-- What is your specific problem you want to solve? -->


<!-- What have you tried so far and where you got stucked? -->


<!-- Please provide some code snippet, reproducible step-by-step or screenshot for clarification. -->
```

Comment: I think this would be a great idea.